# Database Connection Issue

Tags: php

I cannot connect to my database and I do not understand why.

I've run my php in a php checker with no errors.

I'm watching an online course and following the instructions to the letter, yet I'm getting the 'http 500 error' when I try to test and see if it works.

Heres my php:

```
<?php

//STEP 1. Declare params of user information
$email = htmlentities($_REQUEST["email"]);
$password = htmlentities($_REQUEST["password"]);

$test = "test";

if (empty($email) || empty($password)) {

    $returnArray["status"] = "400";
    $returnArray["message"] = "Missing required information";
    echo json_encode($returnArray);
    return;
    }

//secure password
$salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(20);
$secured_password = sha1($password . $salt);

//build connection
//secure way to build connection
$file = parse_ini_file("../caps.ini");

//store in php var info from ini var
$host = trim($file["dbhost"]);
$user = trim($file["dbuser"]);
$pass = trim($file["dbpass"]);
$name = trim($file["dbname"]);


// include access.php to call func from access.php file 
require("secure/access.php");
$access = new access($host, $user, $pass, $name);
$access->connect();

?>
```

And here is the `caps.ini` file I made in a text editor, I've omitted the information here:

```
; Connection information
[section]
dbhost = omitted
dbuser = omitted
dbpass = omitted
dbname = omitted
```

And finally this is my php file where I reference my connection function:

```
<?php

//Declare class to access this php file
class access {

    //connection global variables
    var $host = null;
    var $user = null;
    var $pass = null;
    var $name = null;
    var $conn = null;
    var $result = null;

    // constructing class
    function __construct($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname) {

    $this->host = $dbhost;
    $this->user = $dbuser;
    $this->pass = $dbpass;
    $this->name = $dbname;

    }

    // Connection Function
    public function connect() {

        //establish connection and store it in $conn
        $this->conn = new msqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->name);

        //if error
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo 'Could not connect to database';
        } else {
            echo "Connected";
        }
        //support all languages
        $this->conn->set_charset("utf8");

    }

    //disconnection function
    public function disconnect() {

        if ($this->conn != null) {
        $this->conn->close();
        }

    }


}
```

Here is my folder structure as well:

[image]

Comment: In your php I would try echo'ing something like echo "here"; followed by die(); and put it at the top of the page and move it down till you find where the problem is occuring.

Comment: Can you connect to your Database Server with another client? also `new msqli(` doesn't look right, perhapps you meant `new mysqli(` which you would have found with error reporting enabled.

Comment: What is your first file's path on the server? The file with `// Step 1` in it

Comment: You're generating a random salt on every page load and then never saving it. Nobody will ever be able to log in. You should use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. Edit: Oh wait, I see, you just didn't post that part of the code. Still, don't use SHA1, it's not sufficient for security purposes.

Comment: also try hard-coding your $host, $user, $password, $name just long enough to verify that the values are correct. If correct, something wrong with getting the values from your file; otherwise, you need to provide the correct info.

Comment: Thank you Scuzzy that was my problem! I was driving myself crazy trying to figure out the issue. Thanks to everyone else too

Comment: @m_schafe You should review http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php so you can set development level error messages instead of seeing a blank screen.

Comment: sorry, also http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors may be needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption is this typo around `msqli` vs `mysqli`

```
$this->conn = new msqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->name);
```

should be

```
$this->conn = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->name);
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks!